# Content overflows parent absolute div

Tags: html, overflow, absolute

Please help me to resolve issue. I have simple page structure with absolute dive 100% height as content wrapper. I put my content (red block) inside this block and every time it longer than page height my content ugly overflows parent div. How to solve it? Here is the quick link how it looks: http://bigmedved.ru/stack/

I need a solution without scroll bar for contents and of course the way then it will be hidden.

My CSS

```
@import url("bootstrap.css");

html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #4D5360;
  margin:0;
}

body > .row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;

}

/*Page Structure*/

#main-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#responsive-admin-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height:auto !important;
  left:0px;
  top:67px;
  bottom:0px;
 z-index:20;
}

#content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 52px;
padding:15px;
bottom:15px;
margin:15px 15px 0 0;
left: 190px;
height: auto !important;
right: 0px;
background:#f1f1f1;
box-shadow:0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#red {
    position:relative;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #900;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Mindblow</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
</nav>

<div id="main-wrap">
<div id="responsive-admin-menu">
ssss

</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="red">
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
    <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
    <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>
  <p>Content Here </p>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe you need to change position for "#content-wrapper" to relative?.So, all contents(red block) would be inside it.http://jsfiddle.net/gau9s/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **overflow** on the content-wrapper parent container:

```
#content-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

`overflow: hidden` will hide the overflow without a scroll. There are [more options](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in that case my content will be hiding or scrollbar appears in case of overflow: auto. Both variants are bad solution.